# Python Scrapy Crawler - trying to auto log an issue on Github not working - Gist cannot be created on Linux machines (works on Windows)

Tags: python, scrapy, github-api

We use a script to crawl data and when in error to auto log an issue in GIT

Since recently we are receiving the error below and it *only* seems to appear on Linux machines and not on windows machines. The magical message is "Whoops, files can't contain malformed path components."

**Question**: What is the exact error in this message that needs to be fixed?

Doubts ... is it the code or the file path? ... also only several references to this specific error can be found in Google .. code shared

Error msg

```
github.GithubException.GithubException: 422 {'message': 'Validation Failed', 
'errors': [{'resource': 'Gist', 'code': 'invalid', 'field': 'files'}, 
{'resource': 'Gist', 'code': 'custom', 'field': 'Whoops,', 
'message': "Whoops, files can't contain malformed path components."}], 
'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist'}
```

Code

```
    def create_github_issue(self):
        title = f"Spider needs fix: {self.job.status_comment} - Error in {self.brand_code}:{self.name} - log attached"
        self.logger.info("Creating a github issue called {}".format(title))
        client = Github(GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        github_user = client.get_user()
        repo = client.get_repo("repo/myrepo")

        # check if there already is an open issue
        issues = repo.get_issues()
        for issue in issues:
            if title ==  issue.title:
                self.logger.info("Ignoring github issue, same issue already exists {}".format(title))
                return

        file_objects = []
        gist_urls = []

        attachments = self.email_attachments.copy()
        for attachment in attachments:  # create file objects for all logs
            filter_log(attachment, self.name)  # filters log
            filtered_log_path = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, '{} - '.format(self.name) + os.path.basename(attachment))  # new filter log location
            if os.path.getsize(filtered_log_path) > 0:
                file_objects.append(
                    create_input_file(file_path=filtered_log_path)
                )
            else:
                self.logger.info(f'File {filtered_log_path} is empty')

        attachments.append('Stats')  # add stats, so the zip between attachments and file_objects will work

        file_objects.append(create_input_file(content=self.job.stats))  # add a gist with the stats of the job run
        for attachment, file_object in zip(attachments, file_objects):  # create all gists
            gist_urls.append(
                github_user.create_gist(False, {attachment: file_object}).html_url
            )

        previous_job = self.job.previous_job()
        issue_body = \
            f"An error occurred while crawling {self.name}\n\n" \
                f"Code: {self.brand_code}\n" \
                f"Brand: {self.name}\n" \
                f"Crawl start: {self.job.start_dt.strftime('%x %X')}\n" \
                f"Crawl end: {self.job.finish_dt.strftime('%x %X')}\n" \
                f"Prev. crawl date: {previous_job.start_dt.strftime('%x')}\n" \
                f"Pages: {self.job.pages_count}\n" \
                f"Prev. pages: {previous_job.pages_count}\n" \
                f"Items: {self.job.items_count}\n" \
                f"Prev. items: {previous_job.items_count}\n\"" \
                f"Total products: {self.job.available_items_count}\n" \
                f"Total variants: {self.job.total_qty_count}\n" \
                f"Crawl time: {self.job.crawl_time()}\n\n" \
                f"Status: {self.job.status_comment}\n" \
                f"Enabled: {self.brand.is_enabled}\n" \
                f"Export metadata: {self.brand.export_all_metadata}\n" \
                f"Export stock: {self.brand.export_stock}\n\n"

        for attachment, url in zip(attachments, gist_urls):  # add all gist title's + gists to the issue body
            issue_body += f"{os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(attachment))} - {url}\n"  # adds log file locations to the issue

        repo.create_issue(
            title=title,
            body=issue_body
        )
```